# Как правильно вычесть процент от числа?

Tags: php, математика

Нужно запрограммировать на PHP, чтобы имея число 103 (например) мы могли узнать число без %. (% = 3% от суммы).

То есть 100 + 100 * 0.03 = 103

А нужно получить обратное число.

103 ??? = 100

```
<?php
$amount = 100;
$amount = $amount / 100 * 3; получили 103
$amount = (float)$amount; 
$amount = ???; // на выходе нужно получить 100
echo $amount;
```

Comment: Математика без связи с программированием не входит в тематику сайта.

Comment: исправил вопрос

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не имеет отношения к программированию

Comment: @Александр, перечитайте вопрос внимательнее

Comment: @Abmin вы код добавили, конечно. Но проблема всё ещё не в плоскости программирования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вы получаете проценты `p`? Умножением на `1+p/100`. Соответственно, для получения исходного надо поделить на `1+p/100`...

Т.е. если вы знаете комиссию `p`, и полученную в результате сумму `s`, то сумма комиссии составляет `s - s/(1+p/100) = s*p/(p+100)`. Для `s=103` и `p=3` имеем сумму комиссии `103*3/103 == 3`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58555/discussion-on-answer-by-harry------).